# Place a figure at the beginning/end of a specific page

Tags: floats, positioning

So I'm putting together a paper using LaTeX and I know that I want to place a specific figure at the bottom of page 1, another figure at the top of page 2, etc, and let the text just wrap around the figures.

However, I find that if I try something like `\begin{figure}[b]`, it places the image not at the end of the current page, but rather at the end of the entire document. Is there no way to just say, "this figure goes at the bottom of the first page"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[!b]` probably works if the figure fits The `!` tells latex to ignore numeric constraints. As you didn't supply an example I'm having to guess but maybe your class is inhibiting floats on the first page (the standard classes only inhibit top floats) `!` would over-rule this. Also of course make sure that the figure appears early enough in the source.

Comment: Weird. I thought I had already tried this. Maybe I was doing [b!]. For future record I was using ''\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}'' as my document class.

Comment: What would be the `[command]` for placing the figure at the top of page 2?