# Placing a float at the end of page number (x)

Tags: floats, positioning

So sometimes I'd kinda like to position my floats (tables, figures) in specific places in a document (bottom of second column on the first page, top of the third page, etc) and have the text fill up the space around it, rather than having the floats (apparently very loosely) connected to where they are placed in the text.

I found this [similarly-worded question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75923/place-a-figure-at-the-beginning-end-of-a-specific-page), but the question allowed for the possibility of forcing the figure to be on the page that the text is on (which is how it was resolved). I'd like it if it were possible to even just have a list of figures and no text but still have the floats arranged how I want. Is there a package that does this sort of thing?

Comment: Have you seen [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764)?

Comment: @Werner Both of these have a lot to do with where they are mentioned in text. I'd like to be able to use an environment at least float-like (figure, table, etc) where you can just list all the figures at the top and say, "This one goes at the bottom of the first page, this one on the second page in the second column", etc, even if there's no text at all in the document.

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX3 xor output routine has this functionality but note this is a highly experimental code. However it is available from the repository at

http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/xpackages/xor/

Comment: Which of these files has the documentation necessary to figure out how to make it work to do this?

Comment: 10 years ago I could probably have directed you at exactly the line of code but I'm a bit out the loop these days. Start from http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/xpackages/xor/xo-pfloat.pdf

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just tried the link again from here and it worked for me (linked to the pdf documentation)